# Square a list of lists - ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I know how to square elements of a list, but how to square in list of lists?

To square an element of a list i could use, for example:

```
List.map (fun x -> x*x) [1; 2; 3];;
```

How to do this on list of lists?

```
[[1; 2]; [2; 3]]  --> [[1; 4]; [4; 9]]
```

or

```
[[1; 2; 3]; [4; 2; 0]] --> [[1; 4; 9]; [16; 4; 0]]
```

for example.

Thanks

Comment: Make an internal function squaring elements of a list, then use it. I don't understand why is it difficult to you, if you already know how to square elements of a list. And show the code of your function squaring elements of a list. Also, show the code that you tried to solve your exercise.

Comment: `List.map (fun x -> x*x) [1; 2; 3];;` for example is something i could use on a list to get squares of elements, i don't know how to use this on list of lists.

Comment: Put that code in the question. And you can use `List.map` on any list, including in particular lists of lists of integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let square = fun x -> x * x;;
(* val square : int -> int = <fun> *)

List.map square;;
(* - : int list -> int list = <fun> *)

List.map (List.map square);;
(* - : int list list -> int list list = <fun> *)

List.map (List.map (fun x -> x*x)) [[1; 2]; [2; 3]];;
(* - : int list list = [[1; 4]; [4; 9]] *)
```