# Using the map function in 2d lists?

Tags: multidimensional-array, ocaml, map-function

```
let lst = [[1;2;3];[4;5;6]];;
```

How do I use a map function in a 2D array in OCaml(Lists are immutable) such that I can square every element and get : -

```
lst = [[1;4;9];[16;25;36]];;
```

Comment: You will be using `List.map` twice. One to iterate across the main list and the other will be called for each element.

Comment: following RichN:  let sq_list l = List.map (fun x -> x*x) l ;; for squaring a list of int. let sq_list_list ll = list.map (fun l -> sq_list l) ll;; for squaring the list of list.

Comment: @PierreG. If you loose an unneeded fun wrapping it reads better (imo): `let sq_list_list ll = List.map sq_list ll`. Some people even prefer point-free notation: `let sq_list_list = List.map sq_list`.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129606/square-a-list-of-lists-ocaml

Answer (score 5):

You could write a `mapmap : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list list -> 'b list list` that works like the regular `map : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list` by using `map` twice:

```
(* Apply 'List.map f' to each xs in xss *)
let mapmap f xss = List.map (fun xs -> List.map f xs) xss

(* Written a bit shorter *)
let mapmap f = List.map (List.map f)
```

Then writing `square : int list list -> int list list` becomes:

```
let square = mapmap (fun x -> x*x)
```

Comment: Minor stylistic suggestion:  `let mapmap f = List.(map @@ map f)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it for a simple list do

`# List.map (fun x -> x + 1) [1;2;3;4];;
- : int list = [2; 3; 4; 5]`

As here is a List of lists:

```
let square ll = List.map (fun x->(List.map (fun inner -> inner*inner)x))ll ;;

example:

    # let x = [[1;2;3];[10;11;12]];;
val x : int list list = [[1; 2; 3]; [10; 11; 12]]
```

your function to square your elements:

```
     let square ll = List.map (fun x->(List.map (fun inner -> inner*inner)x))ll
  ;;
val square : int list list -> int list list = <fun>
```

results in:

```
   square x;;
- : int list list = [[1; 4; 9]; [100; 121; 144]]
```